# Can try and catch statements be written inside user defined php function

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, try-catch

I have following code with basic check conditions which is used to filter data using mysql and php.

I have two procedures named **proc_report** and **proc_report_filtered** one which gets all the data and one which displays data based on from and to filters set in the form. ( **submit_filter** is name of submit button, **from** and **to** are two input fields in the form. )

Previously the code used to work and display all the data when try and catch statements are written in place of display_default_data(); in else sections. But to shorten the code I have made use of function display_default_data() to avoid rewriting the same piece of code again and again. But surprisingly when I run this code I see no results.

```
<?php
    function display_default_data()
    {
        try {
            $records = $db->query("call proc_report");
            $records->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            die("Some problem getting data from database !!!" . $e->getMessage());
        }
    }

    if (isset($_POST['submit_filter'])) {
        if (isset($_POST['from'], $_POST['to'])) {
            if (!empty($_POST['from']) && !empty($_POST['to'])) {
                try {
                    $from = $_POST['from'];
                    $to = $_POST['to'];
                    $records = $db->prepare("CALL proc_report_filtered(?,?)");
                    $records->execute(array($from, $to));
                } catch (PDOException $e) {
                    die("Some problem getting data from database !!!" . $e->getMessage());
                }
            } else {
                echo "Enter some values before pressing Filter button !";
                display_default_data();
            }
        } else {
            echo "Please set values ";
            display_default_data();
        }
    } else {
        display_default_data();
    }
?>
```

Is this the right way to use functions and try, catch statements in php? Please suggest me if am going wrong anywhere.

Also I feel the code is quite lengthy ? Any better suggestions to shorten it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can try and catch statements be written inside user defined php function?

Yes.

> Is this the write way to use functions and try, catch statements in php?

NO. [You should never catch an error exception to report it](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#errors). Just leave PDOExceptions alone.

> Also I feel the code is quite lengthy?

Awfully lengthy. All the code you need is just

```
<?php
if (!empty($_POST['from']) && !empty($_POST['to'])) {
    $records = $db->prepare("CALL proc_report_filtered(?,?)");
    $records->execute(array($_POST['from'], $_POST['to']));
} else {
    $records = $db->query("call proc_report");
}
// here you can start displaying your records.
```

Comment: It looks compact but arent we missing to check if the variables are isset and submit button is pressed ( isset submit_filter in my case )

Comment: Nope we aren't. Name a single reason why do we need these checks

Comment: I have used isset with submit_filter to check if the button is clicked. Since we need to execute the code only when the button is clicked. Also isset to check if values of from and to are set or not. The code you have suggested perfectly but I would like to know why isset is not used. In tutorials I have seen people using it and say good practice to use both isset and not empty. Can you please explain the importance of isset ? Also one last question. You have also skipped (  $records->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); ) is not required to mention the fetchmode everytime ?

Comment: Any tutorial that says you have to use both isset and empty at once you should throw away, as its author never read the PHP manual which [says](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) " A variable is considered empty **if it does not exist** or if its value equals FALSE." Means if variable is not empty it is **always** set.

Comment: Thank you for your clear explanation. However can you tell me about fetchmode too. Sorry for asking simple basic questions. I just learned php through online tutorials hence have such basic questions while working with it. Thank you for your time and patience in answering my questions.

Comment: For the fetchmode, just set it once as a default mode in the PDO connector, like shown [here](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#dsn) and it will be the same for all your fetches

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with `try`/`catch`. Instead, the issue is that you are accessing `$records` in your function outside of its scope.

Since you are only writing to it anyway, you can just **return** the value and assign it to your variable at the caller site:

```
function display_default_data()
{
    try {
        $records = $db->query("call proc_report");
        $records->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        return $records;
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        die("Some problem getting data from database !!!" . $e->getMessage());
    }
}

/* ... */

$records = display_default_data(); // instead of just display_default_data();
```

Note that the `$records` *inside* of `display_default_data` and the `$records` *outside* are two different variables which just happen to have the same (local) name.

Comment: I have tried returning $records in display_default_data() and collecting it in $records outside as you have suggested. But still the code doesnt work.

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? Try putting `die` with some message in different places, possibly with a `var_dump` of some variable before to debug your code and see where the code takes an unintended path.